# Any idea how to fit text width to screen

Tags: objects, transforms

What I need is a way to dynamically fit text to a certain size. So more characters, smaller the text size, less characters, bigger the letter. I tried lattice, drivers, various constranints bit didn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

### Simple Driver

A possible solution could be adding a Scripted Expression Driver to the Font Size Property:

```
fact / len(bpy.data.objects['Text'].data.body)
```

where:

*fact* is the multiplier that determines the Font Size (in this case *fact* = 1)

*Text* is the object name

[image]

[image]

### Reference

This solution is "text agnostic" (since it is based on dimensions, it works with every characters)

Make a linked copy (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) of the text object and use the copy as reference to calculate the scale.

1. Add drivers to the Scale Property
2. Use this formula in the X Scale
   Driver (see picture below):

   ```
   0.7 * container/reference
   ```

   where:

   *container* is a new variable from container dimension.x (the blu rectangle)

   *reference* is a new variable from reference dimension.x (the linked copy of the text object)

   *0.7* is the factor to fit the text into the container
3. Copy the X Scale Value to the Y Scale Value:

[image]

This is the final result:

[image]

Changing the reference and container size, the text size will change accordingly.

Move the reference object on a hidden layer...

Comment: Fine for a non proportional font.  For a proportional font "iiiiiiiiiii" will be a lot narrower than "mmmmmmmmmm" (both 10 chars).  That's why I asked re object scale, and use the dimensions of the text object.

Comment: I've added an alternative that uses dimensions instead character count

Comment: Hey, this actually worked. I had to enable python auto-execution for this, and I hope that won't cause me any security issues, but it did just what I needed it to do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another method using a property for the screen_width with an update method.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatProperty

def glonk(self, context):
    text_objs = [o for o in self.objects if o.type == 'FONT']
    for o in text_objs:
        o.dimensions.x = self.screen_width       
        o.scale.y = o.scale.x

    return None

bpy.types.Scene.screen_width = FloatProperty(default=1.0, min=0.0, max=10.0, step=0.1,  update=glonk)

def draw_textwidth(self, context):
    self.layout.prop(context.scene, "screen_width", slider=True)

#bpy.types.DATA_PT_font.remove(draw_textwidth)   
bpy.types.DATA_PT_font.append(draw_textwidth)
```

Adds a slider to the font panel. 
The x dimension of all text objects is set to scene.screen_width and their y scale changed to match the new x scale.

Doesn't update automatically like a driver, will need to click in and out of slider.

[image: Usage]

Comment: Wow, a lot of this is out of my league, but I'll try to figure out scripting for this solution. Thanks!

Comment: As a driver based approach this would be dimension driven by scene.screen_width (or a constant) & scale.y driven by scale.x. On each text object in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

You can force your text object to fill a certain size, but not to scale font size accordingly: if you create a curve (2 points) and make it straight (edit mode > select all vertices > V key > Vector), then you can use that curve object (shaped as a segment) to fit the text: just select it from the text object "text on curve" selector (object data, under font panel)

all the text object letters will shrink to fit the curve length. If you change the curve length, the text will fit. If you add text, it will fit anyway.

Maybe you can use some code (drivers?) to evaluate how much text changes (before/after), and then scale its font size, but is though, since not all letters have same widths... just an idea :)

Comment: This only works if the text is larger then the curve. If you the curve is lager than the text's length,  then the text won't really grow to fill the curve.

Comment: Currently my concern is that text which is fed to Blender via external script doesn't go off screen. So smaller is ok, larger than certain length is a problem. I'll try this solution.