# Counting amount of lines in a text object

Tags: python

How would I go about getting the line count for a text object in Blender using Python?

Example:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Line count = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`TextCurve.body`**

[image]

Split the text curve body by a newline. Count the result.

```
>>> D.objects['Text'].data
bpy.data.curves['Text']

>>> D.curves['Text'].body

'Line 1\nLine 2'

>>> len(D.curves['Text'].body.split("\n"))
2
```

for overflowing text,

[image]

one method to guestimate this would be to set overflowing textbox X size to desired width and Y size to 0. A copy of the object with only one character will have the height of one line.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

text = context.object
copy = text.copy()
font = copy.data = text.data.copy()
font.body = "0"
context.collection.objects.link(copy)
context.scene.update()
print(round(text.dimensions.y / copy.dimensions.y))
bpy.data.objects.remove(copy)
```

If there is line spacing then two lines will be 2 x line height + line space.  I vaguely recall a more accurate way to calculate font dimension, but have not fount the link.

Related [Any idea how to fit text width to screen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39275/any-idea-how-to-fit-text-width-to-screen)

**`Text.lines`**

[image]

Python console code.

```
>>> D.texts['Text']
bpy.data.texts['Text']

>>> len(D.texts['Text'].lines)
2

>>> for line in D.texts['Text'].lines:
...     line.body
...     
'line 1'
'line 2'
```

Comment: I should have been clearer. What I meant was getting the line count of text that is in an text object not from a text file, as I see no way of detecting when Blender decides where line breaks should be (which is affected by the text box width. See: https://i.imgur.com/EHS3W88.png

Comment: I guess I could find the Height dimension of a single line and divide that by the Height dimension of the entire text object to get a rough estimate of the line count, but that seems like a dirty way of going about it

Comment: Hm.. That seems to work for text that I enter myself with newlines and all, but the text I wanted the line count for is read in from a file. There is only 1 linebreak there, which comes from being a new paragraph. It doesn't seem like Blender inserts "\n" when text is wrapping. I did however get the correct value of linecount by doing this

`round(textObject.dimensions[1]/0.1)`, where the 0.1 comes from checking the width of a single line manually at a given text size. It's not perfect nor pretty, but I guess it works

Comment: lol.. "great minds think alike" added to answer before seeing this.